# Waving flag effect in vertex shader

Tags: opengl

I am looking to create a waving flag effect in a vertex shader and here is what i have so far:

```
#version 330

layout(location = 0) in vec3 in_position;       
layout(location = 1) in vec3 in_color;      

uniform mat4 model_matrix, view_matrix, projection_matrix;
uniform vec3 culoare;
uniform float currentAngle;

out vec3 vertex_to_fragment_color;

void main(){

vertex_to_fragment_color = culoare;

vec4 v = vec4( in_position.x, in_position.y, in_position.z, 1.0 );

v.y  = sin( in_position.x + currentAngle );
v.y += sin( in_position.z + currentAngle );
v.y *= in_position.x * 0.08;

gl_Position = projection_matrix*view_matrix*model_matrix*v; 
}
```

current_angle is a variable that i'm sending to the shader and it kind of looks like this:

```
if ( currentAngle > 360.0f ) currentAngle -= 360.0f;
if ( currentAngle < 0.0f   ) currentAngle += 360.0f;
```

I am new to this so i could really use some help to get this right.

Comment: Waving flags usually have motion in more than one direction. A sine wave applied in one direction is not going to look particularly convincing. You probably want to displace X or Z too. That said, you really have not described what is actually ***wrong*** with what you tried. As already mentioned, the trig. functions in GLSL use radians rather than degrees for angle measures and you need subdivision to make waving recognizable when done per-vertex.

Answer (score 1):

GLSL's `sin()` and `cos()` take their arguments in radians, not degrees.

You can use the GLSL function `radians()` to convert degrees to radians.

You'll also have to subdivide your flag rectangle to get a convincing effect.